# how to upload arguments to env from config_file in dockerfile?

Tags: dockerfile

I have the config_file which contains many arguments:

```
FOO=/foo
FOO_1=/bar
...
FOO_100=/opt
```

I need to set my env in docker container, which will contain all these arguments.

I know about --build-arg option, but I don't think it's a good idea, because number of arguments is too big.

So, I don't know how to load environment variables into container correctly.

Comment: Does https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/ help you? That's the very first result you receive on Google, and it shows exactly what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the --env-file argument while running to the container

ex:

docker run --env-file config.env

check docker run options here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#options

alternative docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  test:
    image: test: image
    env_file:
      - config.env
```

you can refer for more details https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/